# How to resolve unmet dependencies of all applications in Ubuntu 16 version?

Tags: grub2, package-management, software-center

Recently, I was trying to install scipy, but I stopped the prpcess in midway. After that, ubuntu always start with grub recovery menu. Then,  when I tried to resolve the issue with disk check, clean and other options... It doesnt resolve.

In dpkg, i get bus error or error that python is missing a variable.

When i boot ubuntu in recovery mode, i can not see any applications in Dash. I have used sudo apt-get clean, autoclea,, auto remove, update, upgrade,  -f update but it all ends with list of all applications with unmet dependencies and package reading error and that there is corrupted cache.

I tried using the gnome-software....software center... and removed the softwares but they dont. They appear again.

I noticed that i can use the application if i try to Open.it from.terminal butvi cannot install anything.

Please help. I am new to ubuntu. I have to starta project on Python soon.

Answer (score 0):

Someone maybe able to provide a better answer, but if you still have your original install media, you can reset your OS back to a default state and it should keep all your documents. However, it's never a bad idea to back them up.

Comment: I dont have it right now. thats the problem. I have the backup, but i was wondering if it could be resolved without the os reinstall. Otherwise, i would have to download ubuntu and the, resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

First clean the corrupted `apt` lists:

`sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Then run `sudo apt update`

The problem will be solved

Comment: I have tried this. This didnt work for me.